# TeXworks does not search its own directory

Tags: miktex, texworks

Here is the story yesterday I tried to make pdf using texworks from my tex files
It asked me for two different style files I add one of them using miktex package manager and for second one I add the package folder as root in miktex setting
The file was converted to pdf (it doesn't have any picture or references).
After that when I want to generate pdf using It shows me lots of "not found" error.
And it doesn't look for style file , pictures or .bib in its own folder 
Anybody have Idea about how can I fix it?

following part is added for clarification:

texwork works like this: if my *.tex file is stored like "C:program file/test/a.tex" and I use for example "\usepackage{amsmath}" in my code it looks for this file in "C:program file/test/" if it couldn't find it in its own library. The problem is it does not searching this directory("C:program file/test/" ) anymore **like it used to do(same code, same classes and ...)**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you update MiKTeX's filename database?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. TeXWorks doesn't include any style files, pictures of BibTeX database files itself. It is just an editor. Please explain what you did in detail and provide the exact text of the error messages you receive, together with the code which generates them.

Comment: Adding a package folder as root is wrong. (latex) packages must be in a suitable subfolder below a root: root/tex/latex/package.

Comment: @Mico Yes I updated database.

Comment: @cfr latex works like this: if my *.tex file is stored like "C:program file/test/a.tex" and I use for example "\usepackage{amsmath}" in my code it looks for this file in "C:program file/test/" if it couldn't find it in its own library. The problem is it does not searching this directory("C:program file/test/" ) anymore like it used to do

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than giving a loose description of what you have done it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile, if possible. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Comment: @Andrew As I mentioned above I did not do anything to code and the code which had been compiled perfectly does not compile anymore. so I think it does not matter which package I use.I have same problem with all of my *.tex files I think it is related to software configuration.

Comment: OK, so you haven't changed anything and it used to work, *but* you also have not really told us very much about your set up or what errors you are getting so it is basically impossible for people to help as they can't see your computer and, as far as I know, none of us are psychic. Give us a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) and some one *may* be able to help you. I'm not trying to be difficult but I doubt that anyone can help you from the information that is currently in your question.